# How Conv2D works in Tensorflow/PyTorch when two layers are connected with different filter numbers?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, conv-neural-network

After reviewing LeNet5 architecture description, when Max Pooling layer (with 6 filters) is connected with Conv2D layer (16 filters), there is a requirement of special filter mapping, in the following way:

1. Taking inputs from every contiguous subset of 3 feature maps
2. Taking inputs from every contiguous subset of 4 feature maps
3. Taking inputs from every contiguous subset of 4 feature maps
4. Taking inputs from the discontinuous subset of 4 feature maps
5. Taking all the feature maps

A slightly annotated image from LeNet paper, courtesy of TowardsAI

[image]

Here recall this mapping is pretty specialized to 10 <-> 16, whereas Tensorflow/PyTorch is pretty flexible, just wonder how Tensorflow/PyTorch handles it exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the actual implementation of this network in those frameworks. However, here's one way you can implement such an operation in PyTorch.

---

You can look at this operation as a [change of basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis): going from feature maps in the **'S2' space** to feature maps in the **'C3' space** using a transform matrix `M`. The whole objective is to construct that matrix, it is composed of ones and zeros, where the ones are positioned such that you construct vectors in **C3 space** using components of vectors in **S2 space**.

For instance, let's look at the **discontinuous subsets of 4** of the table: column `#12` requires maps n°`0`, `1`, `3`, and `4`. The corresponding row in `M` for vector `#12` will therefore be `[1,1,0,1,1,0]`. Essentially, the `1`s here correspond to the crosses shown in the figure. For this particular portion of the transition `M` will look like:

```
tensor([[1., 0., 1.],
        [1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 1., 1.],
        [1., 0., 1.],
        [1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 1., 1.]])
```

To actually perform the matrix multiplication, you can use [`torch.einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html):

```
torch.einsum('bchw,cd->bdhw', x, M)
```

---

Here's an example: starting from a 6-channel 2x2 map and transitioning to a 3-channel 2x2 map (defined by columns `#12`, `#13`, and `#14` of the **Table I**):

```
>>> x = torch.rand(1,6,2,2)
tensor([[[[0.3134, 0.2468],
          [0.2759, 0.4971]],

         [[0.4150, 0.8735],
          [0.6726, 0.0463]],

         [[0.9547, 0.5338],
          [0.0654, 0.7458]],

         [[0.4099, 0.1984],
          [0.0930, 0.8054]],

         [[0.1695, 0.1586],
          [0.7961, 0.3894]],

         [[0.5535, 0.0678],
          [0.1484, 0.7735]]]])

>>> torch.einsum('bchw,cd->bdhw', x, M)
tensor([[[[1.3077, 1.4773],
          [1.8377, 1.7382]],

         [[2.0926, 1.6338],
          [1.6825, 1.9550]],

         [[2.2315, 1.0467],
          [0.5828, 2.8219]]]])
```

You can of course expand this operation to the whole of **Table I**, this would result in a matrix `M` of size `6x16`.

Comment: Great thanks for the neat Tensorflow code! I guess maybe one idea of the implementation is some form of automated change of basis + a more efficient way of such function.

Comment: This operation can be implemented with NumPy (for TensorFlow) in the same way. Does this give an answer to your question?

Comment: Yeah, for sure!